# Getting 'orderBy' undefined error when testing Vue component using lodash with Jest

Tags: vue.js, lodash, jestjs

Have a Vue app that has lodash imported into `main.js` like:

`import lodash from 'lodash'`

`Vue.use(VueLodash, lodash)`

I can then use the lodash orderBy function in my single file components like:
`this._.orderBy(this.comments, 'updated_at', 'desc')`

That all works fine.

When I run tests with Jest though it throws the following error:
`Cannot read property 'orderBy' of undefined`

How do I get Jest to recognise _ in the same way as Vue?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @silva96 I've added an answer, in case you're still looking for one

Answer (score 0):

I could fix a similar issue (with the help of [this article](https://di-rk.medium.com/vue-js-test-from-dust-to-light-1a5e4439fe26)).
TLDR:
Add to your component spec a "localVue" and then use lodash with this localVue instance:

```
import YourComponent from '@/YourComponent.vue'
import { createLocalVue, mount, config } from '@vue/test-utils'
import VueLodash from 'vue-lodash'
import lodash from 'lodash'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(VueLodash, { lodash })

...

const wrapper = mount(YourComponent, {
  localVue
})
```